# Excel: Conditions with multiple files

Tags: excel

In a file, I have a list with numbers. I also have multiple other files.

I want to look, which numbers in the list, is in one of the other files.

Example:
`Here, a column means a opend file`

| list.xlsb | filename_1.xlsb | filename_2.xlsb | filename_3.xlsb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 32 | 111 | 22 |
| 222 | 23 | 44 | 222 |
| 333 | 223 | 424 | 212 |

The Output next to the list in the file list.xls should be:

| list.xlsb | output |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | "filename_2" |
| 222 | "filename_3" |
| 333 | "Not exist" |

It should show me, where in the files is the number.
If the number doesnt exist in all of the files, the output should be "not exist".

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(F2;'[filename_1.xlsb]Table1'!A:A;1;False)=F2;"KW03";"Not Exist")
```

I am not sure how to do it with multiple files.

Comment: Something like this? It's ugly code but it should work (once adjusted to your need): `IFERROR(IF(<firstVLOOKUP>;"firstFileName";1/0); IFERROR(IF(<secondVLOOKUP>;"secondFileName";1/0);etc.);"Not Exist")`

Comment: ```=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F6;'KW3'!A:A;1);"KW3";1/0);IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F6;'KW4'!A:A;1);"KW4";1/0));"Not exists")```

Can you see my mistake?

Comment: You're not using your IF(VLOOKUP) = F2) anymore, vlookup isn't a BOOLEAN.

Comment: When I use it, i get as an output ```False```

Comment: I think my brakets are wrong

Comment: So it works: ```=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F6;'KW3'!A:A;1)=F6;"KW3";1/0);IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F6;'KW4'!A:A;1)=F6;"KW4";1/0);IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F6;'KW5'!A:A;1)=F6;"KW5";1/0);"Not exists")))```